# Angular adds margin to divs

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a component that generates forms through objects but I'm having problems with the layout. I've added classes through ngClass so that you can choose the layout through the object and the form is customized but I have this problem:

[image]

The inputs that have col-md-6 placed appear one below the other since a margin is added (which does not really exist). I don't understand absolutely anything that's going on.

Comment: In order to place them side by side you have to put an additional `.row` around both form field containers. It that possible using your existing code?

Comment: All the inputs are generated within a div form-row or row, that's why I can't understand why the columns don't work. The idea is to put them next to each other always but if you want it to be complete you add a col-12